# Идентификация, Аутентификация, Авторизация когда какое слово использовать?

Tags: авторизация, любой-язык, терминология, аутентификация

Может мой вопрос глупый, но у меня возникла путаница в использовании слов Идентификация, Аутентификация и Авторизация.

**Идентификация** – процесс, позволяющий определить пользователя.

**Аутентификация** – процесс подтверждения, что пользователь действительно является тем, за кого себя выдает.

**Авторизация** – процесс определения того, какие действия позволено совершать аутентифицированному пользователю.

Как должен называться сервис/контроллер/модуль, который позволяет пользователю войти в систему?

Форма входа на сайт, это форма идентификации, аутентификации или авторизации?

Comment: я назвал бы его `login` )

Comment: Форма входа на сайт - это форма аутентификации, если вводится имя и пароль (ну или сертификат или что там), или форма идентификации, если вводится только имя пользователя. На основании введённых данных серверная часть может выполнить авторизацию пользователя в тех или иных сервисах или комплексах хранения/обработки данных.

Answer (score 0):

Форма входа на сайт с логином и паролем - это в целом аутентификация. Идентификацию можно рассматривать как часть этой процедуры.

- **Authenticatio**n - проверка подлинности пользователя / клиента (Login Form, HTTP Basic и Digest Auth) или сервера (X.509 certificate).
- **Identification** - процесс выявления идентификатора однозначно идентифицирующего субъект в системе. Для этого этот идентификатор д.б. предварительно назначен, т.е. проведена регистрация субъекта в системе. Идентификация напрямую связана с аутентификацией: субъект проходит аутентификацию и если она успешна, то система на основе факторов аутентификации определяет идентификатор субъекта.
- **Authorization** - процесс проверки права аутентифицированного пользователя на доступ к ресурсу.